# atop not working properly

Tags: monitoring, centos6, top, system-monitoring

I've (yum) installed atop utility in centOS 6.8. But when I run any atop command (eg: atop -a) , it is giving the following error in commandline.

> Malloc failed for current sysstats

However, I'm able to open the raw log file using the command "atop -r /var/log/atop/atop_20170302". But, afer opening it, I can't move back and forth in time when I press "t" and "shift+t". It seems stuck at the same time instance.

> whereis atop
>   atop: /usr/bin/atop /etc/atop

while checking, 'etc/atop/' folder was empty
and also there was no atop service in '/etc/init.d/'

Comment: So how much memory do you have?

Comment: just found the problem. answered it below. Thanks anyway, Michael.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the cause. The server was an openvz vm. atop is not compatible with the kernel of the container.

Thanks